# Possible issues between Meteor datatables packages?

Tags: meteor

I'm in need of some datatables for an admin panel that I'm creating.

I'm looking at either [ephemer:reactive-datatables](https://github.com/ephemer/meteor-reactive-datatables/) or [aldeed:tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular)

These two seem to be the only ones that are still being actively developed.

Both lack good tutorials for how to get things built from scratch.

I've looked at [OrionJS](https://github.com/orionjs/orion) for the entire admin panel and CMS but the documentation is *seriously* lacking. I know they've put in the effort of writing stuff down, but there's no tutorial explaining what things are or why you're doing things and the effects they will have.

I'm looking for some possible issues that I might run into when implementing either of the two packages above.

I know from using aldeed's `autoform` and `simpleSchema` that he creates some very powerful, but complex and hard to understand packages.

`ephemer datatables` seems more simplistic and quicker to get off the ground, but is it lacking any major features or limitations? I don't want to get heavily-invested into a package and then realize there's something that it simply can't do.

- One of my requirements will be to be able to display multiple datatables on one screen.
- Being able to easily style each component on a datatable separately would be amazing, so it should generate some good classes and IDs to hook onto.
- Search/filter is really important. Can I do a reactive search on any data column?
- What about UX things such as changing and saving the value of something right from the table itself without having to go into a separate update form just for that item?
- What about the ease of finding answers to questions about each package? Which is more popular (I'm leaning towards aldeed's one on this just by my gut feeling).